# EmberJS - adapter dynamic namespaces for various models

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an app in EmberJS and RESTful API. Problem is that some resources require dynamic URLs.

For example addresses are a part of contact (with some contact id). So route for adding address in **API** is

```
/api/contacts/3/addresses
```

So I want to query addresses in JSONAPIAdapter in Ember. How Can I do it nicely? I use:

```
this.store.adapterFor('application').set('namespace', "api/contacts/3");
```

But it's ugly, I should be using it before every model, and that's really bad solution. Do I need to rewrite whole JSONAPIAdapter, or there is some other solution?

Comment: Dynamic is going to be difficult definitely...

Answer (score 0):

This is not really `JSONAPI`! But lets look at it.

This looks like a relationship resolving. So you have an address, and wants to find its contacts. Easiest thing for this is just to follow the [`JSONAPI`](http://jsonapi.org). Its clear that the link for a relationship must be specified in the original document. So your contact response should looks like this:

```
{
    data: [{
        id: 3,
        type: 'contact',
        relationships: {
            addresses: {
                links: {
                    related: '/api/contacts/3/addresses'
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

And then everything works out of the box!
If your response does not follow the JSONAPI just in that point you can just fix this in your serializer. But if you are no JSONAPI at all you should use the `RESTAdapter`/`RESTSerializer`. There you can just override [urlForFindHasMany](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_urlForFindHasMany).

Comment: Ok, so if I want to follow an object (for example, contact) in another route in Ember, I need to use the same object, only ask for relationships? Can I for example filter them?

Comment: Well not, it depends on your data structure. Use `findAll` when you want to find all, and absolutely all records of a given type. Resolve a relationship if you want to find all records related to another model. Like all contacts for an address. You can't filter there, so for that use `query` with both your filter data and primary records and handle that in the adapter.